# Apache mod_authnz_ldap Error 500

Tags: apache-2.2, ldap

Ubuntu 12.04 LTS

Apache/2.2.22

`http://server/lightsquid/` gives window with username/password request, then «500 Internal Server Error». Error rises whatever username and password were used: valid or not. If line `Require valid-user` is removed, everything works fine, so problem is in mod_authnz_ldap module.

Module mod_authnz_ldap is enabled. Apache config:

```
Alias           /lightsquid /usr/lib/cgi-bin/lightsquid
<Directory "/usr/lib/cgi-bin/lightsquid">
        AddHandler cgi-script .cgi
        Options +ExecCGI
        Order allow,deny
        Allow from all

        AuthType Basic
        AuthName "USE YOUR WINDOWS ACCOUNT"
        AuthBasicProvider ldap
        AuthzLDAPAuthoritative on
        #AuthzLDAPAuthoritative off
        #AuthUserFile /dev/null

        AuthLDAPBindDN "CN=squid_auth,DC=domain,DC=ru"
        AuthLDAPBindPassword "*****************"
        AuthLDAPURL "ldap://dc2.domain.ru/dc=domain,dc=ru?sAMAccountName?sub?(objectClass=*)"
        Require valid-user

</Directory>
```

Changing `AuthzLDAPAuthoritative off` to

```
AuthzLDAPAuthoritative 
AuthUserFile /dev/null
```

does not help.

LogLevel is debug.

error.log does not have any entries ablut error. In access.log I can see

```
192.168.0.1 - selivanov [15/Feb/2014:11:51:00 +0400] "GET /lightsquid/index.cgi HTTP/1.1" 500 814 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Ubuntu; Linux x86_64; rv:26.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/26.0"
```

How can I force it to give me normal problem diagnostics? Logs are almost empty.

Comment: Are you sure that you've restarted Apache since setting `LogLevel debug`, and that you're looking in the right error file?  The first thing to do in a case like this is always to look in the error log, which must have some information in it.

Comment: Yes, I restarted it.